# probability and order question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, permutations

What is wrong in my  solution ?

Q: If we have $N$ number of light leds, and the probability of having faulty ones is $R$ (in percentage), what is the probability of having 2 or more faulty light leds next to each other?

My solution: using permutation:

$$
P=\left(\frac{2! \, (N -1)!}{N!}\right) R
$$

Any useful links for similar cases is appreciated too.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case of two:

You choose the two positions with $n-1$ ways.

Then you can choose two positions with $\binom{n}{2}$ ways.

If the leds are discrite and only then, you do *:

*Then you permute them with $2!$ ways.

*Then you permute the other elements with $(n-2)!$ ways.

Multiply the possibility of finding two neighbour positions with $R$.

Continue for the case of $3$ until the case of $n-1$.

Sum up!